# Parse html/xml can't filter for text

Tags: html, r, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse some html/xml data and would like to get the ID.
There are multiple snippeds looking like the one below which are written in one file.
Now I'm not able to select all of the ID's because they are not in a specific node or class.

Currently my code is something like that but the filter for the ID's is missing:

```
file %>% html_nodes(".MAINBODY") %>% html_nodes("tr") %>% xml_text()
```

```
<TR><TD HEIGHT=25></TD></TR>
<TR>
  <TD VALIGN=TOP COLSPAN=3>
   <A NAME="76ED699E406E3FA20568F4ABFE2CB24C"></A>
   <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=4 BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR=#000000><TR><TD>
    <TABLE CLASS=OBJECTNAME WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><TR><TD WIDTH=44><IMG SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\FolderL.bmp></TD><TD>Seiten</TD></TR></TABLE>
    <!--========== SECTION: BASIC PROPERTIES ==========-->
    <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY HEIGHT=25><TR><TD></TD></TD></TABLE>
    <TABLE CLASS=SECTIONHEADER WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><TR><TD>BASIC PROPERTIES</TD></TR></TABLE>
    <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><COL WIDTH=120>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Location:</TD><TD>\ Report</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Description:</TD><TD></TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Long Description:</TD><TD></TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Creation Time:</TD><TD>13.11.2020 11:06:22</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Modification Time:</TD><TD>10.01.2022 11:40:55</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Owner:</TD><TD><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\User.bmp>&nbsp;Administrator</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Hidden:</TD><TD>No</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>ID:</TD><TD>76ED699E406E3FA20568F4ABFE2CB24C</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Version ID:</TD><TD>C75E81DC49C748800AD242B04B486C5C</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP>
      <TD>Access Control:</TD>
      <TD>
       <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1>
        <COL WIDTH=33%><COL WIDTH=34%><COL WIDTH=33%>
        <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERLRTB BGCOLOR=#DDDDDD WIDTH=33%>USER</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRTB BGCOLOR=#DDDDDD WIDTH=34%>OBJECT</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRTB BGCOLOR=#DDDDDD WIDTH=33%>CHILDREN</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR VALIGN=TOP>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\Group.bmp>&nbsp;A_Administrator</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRB>Full Control</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRB>Full Control</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR VALIGN=TOP>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\Group.bmp>&nbsp;A_Administrator</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRB>Modify</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRB>Modify</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR VALIGN=TOP>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\Group.bmp>&nbsp;User</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRB>View</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRB>View</TD>
        </TR>
       </TABLE>
      </TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <!--========== SECTION: INTERNATIONAL PROPERTIES ==========-->
    <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY HEIGHT=25><TR><TD></TD></TD></TABLE>
    <TABLE CLASS=SECTIONHEADER WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><TR><TD>INTERNATIONAL PROPERTIES</TD></TR></TABLE>
    <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><COL WIDTH=120>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Default Language:</TD><TD><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\Language.bmp>&nbsp;German</TD></TR>
     <TR VALIGN=TOP><TD>Translations:</TD><TD>       <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY WIDTH=70% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1>
        <COL WIDTH=50%><COL WIDTH=50%>
        <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERLRTB BGCOLOR=#DDDDDD WIDTH=50%>LANGUAGE</TD>
         <TD CLASS=BORDERRTB BGCOLOR=#DDDDDD WIDTH=50%>TRANSLATION</TD>
        </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files\Language.bmp>&nbsp;German</TD>
      <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB>Seiten</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB><IMG ALIGN=MIDDLE SRC=file:///C:\Program Files \Language.bmp>&nbsp;German</TD>
      <TD CLASS=BORDERLRB>Seiten</TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>
                                                                                                                                             </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
   </TD></TR></TABLE>
  </TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN=RIGHT><A CLASS=TOPLINK HREF="#TOP">Top<A/></TD></TR>
```

In this case the return should be:
76ED699E406E3FA20568F4ABFE2CB24C

Came up with a solution by myself if some one is intersted in:

```
ID <- file %>% html_nodes(".MAINBODY tr td") %>% xml_text %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(value = str_trim(value)) %>% slice(value, which(value == "ID") + 1)
```

Comment: Change `xml_text()` to `html_text()`. There is a lot more drilling down you'll have to do.

Comment: On what should I drill down, there aren't more nodes?

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly organized page but with some trial and error you can determine which table your data is in.

Start with this:

```
tables <- page %>% html_elements("table.MAINBODY")
```

To retrieve a list of tables with class="MAINBODY"

If you step through the tables one by one you can see the data of interest is in table 3. This table also contains an embedded table.

```
df<- tables[3] %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
df

answer <- df$X2[df$X1=="ID:"]
```

Not very elegant but gets the job done

Comment: @Chris, if this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer in order to mark it closed.